# Conda Environments directory wrong

Tags: anaconda, conda

Somehow I ended up in a situation where my conda environments want to go into `/Users/derek/miniconda3` instead of `/Users/derek/miniconda3/env`.  I attempted to update the config file but instead this added a line to my `.condarc`.  How do I get it to default back to `.../miniconda3/env` and allow for named environments?  (Currently i have to use the full env path.)

```py
env_prompt: ({default_env})
envs_dirs:
  - /Users/derekchapman/miniconda3
  - /opt/miniconda3/envs
  - /Users/derekchapman/.conda/envs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, the following should do the trick:

```bash
conda config --remove envs_dirs /Users/derekchapman/miniconda3
```

If that doesn’t work, then it is possible there is a `.condarc` file somewhere with this configuration entry. You can track “sources” of Conda configuration settings down, with

```bash
conda config --show-sources
```

and then edit the offending file.

Comment: Fantastic!  I needed to add the actual path first with `conda config --add envs_dirs /Users/derekchapman/miniconda3/envs/` which made my environmentss work with a simple `conda activate fetch_data`.  Then removed the shortened and unwanted path.